# How can I get the cell value by title? Not number index (phpexcel)

Tags: php, phpexcel

In the current version of my project, I can only get a cell value using `getCell("A4")->getValue()`, but there's a  problem, sometime I want to delete or add a column, it will disrupt other values, so I have to sort my data again. 
I want to know if there is a function, that can give me cell using using a number as a column insted of a letter, exemple: "A4" from $title['first'][4], and "B5" from $title['second'][5]
[image of exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DuMQ.png)

Maybe my expression is not clear enough,I hope you can get my point/question, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$colunmn=1; //The colunmn  you want to start the cicle 
$columnMax=5; //The colunmn  you want to end the cicle 
while($coluna < $columnMax){
    $colunmString = PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex($colunmn); //Convert the nº index into a collunm string ex: 1->'A', 2->'B', 27->'AA', 28->'AB'
    getCell($colunmString. "2")->getValue(); //I used "2" as a line exemple you can change it
    $colunmString++;
}
```

You can adapt that code to your needs.
Just use the function `PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex( int )` to get the column string with an int index.